# Accessing data from other databases - system architecture

Tags: database, architecture

I have a system that we have recently developed - a web application over a SQL server database.  The SQL server database has been set up to be a 'multi-tenant' database, with many different 'installations' of our web site accessing the same database.

We have another application that runs along similar lines, the main difference being that it has many different 'installations' all accessing their own seperate databases.

All these websites run on the same server and all the databases reside in the same SQL server instance.

Each of our clients would have one of each of these systems and up to this point, we have had some fairly light integration between these two systems, which has been handled via web service calls.

We now have a new change that is going to require me to return a list of data from the multi-tenant system, but filter it based on criteria stored in the databases of the other system.  I can see a few ways of doing this, but was wondering if anybody had any bright ideas:

1. Web service again - don't like this idea, as it means taking a list of data and making a call for each individual item, which is both slow and ugly.
2. Writing some dynamic SQL within the database layer to do a join on .dbo.table, which is also a bit ugly, and can be hard to maintain.
3. Replicate the data from one database to the other.  This is where I am tending towards, however there then comes a risk of the data getting out of sync.

I'd like to do something clever about views in my multi-tenant database, but I don't want to have to create a seperate set of views each time we create a new database for the second system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on business size I go with `#1` or `#2`.

`#1` is more scalabe and good for heterogenus clients but harder to implement and maintain. Since you do't have public APIs you can go to `#2`.

`#2` needs an expert DBA and very error-prone

`#3` is the worst solution IMO since redundacy would happen and it's hard to resolve later.

What I suggest is a short-term plan and a long-term plan. In short term use `#1` or `#2` and at the same time redesign your database. Then you can add new data model to system and it can coexist with legacy dbase. When you are insure of it's functionality switch to new db but still remain lgacy system. And finally when new db has no problem after a while exit the legacy db from circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the data model. It's risky. Just make another abstract wrapper over it.

You can replicate database on another server and let this new wrapper work with copy of data.
If any data corruption happened, simply restore to main copy.